# magento 2 extra fee not adding to grandtotal in invoice

Tags: magento2, invoice, extrafee

magento 2 extra fee not adding to grandtotal in invoice

block is calling but model is not calling

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>        
    <referenceContainer name="invoice_totals">
        <block class="Custom\LoyaltyProgram\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Order\Invoice\Fee" name="fee"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Block

```
<?php
 namespace Custom\LoyaltyProgram\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Order\Invoice;

class Fee extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
protected $_config;
protected $_order;
protected $_source;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Tax\Model\Config $taxConfig,
    \Custom\LoyaltyProgram\Helper\Data $helper,
    \Custom\LoyaltyProgram\Model\Extrafee $extraFeeModel,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_config = $taxConfig;
    $this->_helper = $helper;
    $this->extraFeeModel = $extraFeeModel;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function displayFullSummary()
{
    return true;
}

public function getSource()
{
    return $this->_source;
} 
public function getStore()
{
    return $this->_order->getStore();
}
public function getOrder()
{
    return $this->_order;
}
public function getLabelProperties()
{
    return $this->getParentBlock()->getLabelProperties();
}

public function getValueProperties()
{
    return $this->getParentBlock()->getValueProperties();
}
public function getInvoice()
{
    return $this->getParentBlock()->getInvoice();
}
 public function initTotals()
{
    $this->getParentBlock();
    $this->getInvoice();
    $this->getSource();

    $parent = $this->getParentBlock();
    $this->_order = $parent->getOrder();
    $this->_source = $parent->getSource();

    $orderId = $this->_order->getId();
    $store = $this->getStore();

    $collection = $this->extraFeeModel->getCollection();
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('order_id', $orderId);

    if($collection->getSize()){

        $extraFee = $collection->getFirstItem()->getFee();
        $extraFee = -1*$extraFee;

        $fee = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
                [
                    'code' => 'fee',
                    'strong' => false,
                    'value' => $extraFee,
                    'label' => $this->_helper->getTitle()
                ]
            );
        $parent->addTotal($fee, 'fee');
    }

    $this->getInvoice()->setGrandTotal($this->getInvoice()->getGrandTotal() - $extraFee); // "2" extra fee
    $logger->info('2getGrandTotalblock'.$this->getInvoice()->getGrandTotal());

    $this->getParentBlock()->addTotalBefore($fee, 'grand_total');
    return $this;

}}
```

Model

```
<?php

namespace Ewall\LoyaltyProgram\Model\Invoice\Total;

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice\Total\AbstractTotal;

class Fee extends AbstractTotal
{
/**
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice $invoice
 * @return $this
 */
public function collect(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice $invoice)
{

$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/fee.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('model calling:');

    $invoice->setFee(0);

    $amount = $invoice->getOrder()->getFee();
    $invoice->setFee($amount);


    $invoice->setGrandTotal($invoice->getGrandTotal() - 2); // 2 extra fee
    $invoice->setBaseGrandTotal($invoice->getBaseGrandTotal() - 2);  // 2 extra fee

    return $this;
}}
```

Comment: please chanfe  <referenceContainer name="invoice_totals"> to  <referenceBlock name="invoice_totals">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forgot to add etc/sales.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/sales.xsd">
<section name="quote">
    <group name="totals">
        <item name="fee" instance="Custom\LoyaltyProgram\Model\Total\Fee" sort_order="150"/>
    </group>  
</section>
 <section name="order_invoice">
    <group name="totals">
        <item name="fee" instance="Custom\LoyaltyProgram\Model\Invoice\Total\Fee" sort_order="160"/>
    </group>
</section>
```